# Cordova Camera Plugin base64 image doesn't get returned

Tags: cordova, vue.js, vuejs2, camera, nuxt.js

I'm integrating the Cordova Camera Plugin into my Nuxt JS/Cordova hybrid app. I'm able to add a button which calls a method when a button is tapped. I'd like to select an image from the camera roll, my method is:

```
/**
 * Change profile photo
 */
changeProfilePhoto() {
  if (this.isApp) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onError, {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      correctOrientation: true
    });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
      this.profile.image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData
    }

    function onError(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
  }
}
```

`imageData` appears to return nothing, I can verify this when I do an `alert(imageData)` which appears to show a tonne of whitespace and takes forever to load.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Nope, simply removed the plugin for now.